# Making hider panel with z-index (css)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a pop-up in one of my pages. Firstly i need a panel which top on everything(Hider Panel). I've tryed it with css z index. But the problem is; my hiderpanel doesn't stand on my navigation bar -Navigation bar from master page- even my navigation bar has lower z-index than hiderpanel.

[image]

Any idea?

> Edit:My contents css:

```css
.wrapper
{   
  
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#313338;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px 0px 10px;
    padding:0px;
    height:30px;
    color:#313338;
    border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    z-index:1;
}
.menu
{
    border-style: none;
    border-color: inherit;
    border-width: medium;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 225px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -225px;
    border-radius: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color:#e6e7e8;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 20px;   
    z-index:1;     
}
.page
{
    top:30px;
    left:200px;
    position:absolute;       
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:80%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:-1;
}

.hiderpanel
{    
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;    
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:15;     
    background: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5);
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="menu"><div>
<div class="page">
  <div class="hiderpanel">
    <div>
  <div>
```

> I cant understand it works here :/

Comment: Can you share your code or a demo

Comment: I've edited my post with code, interesting it works here as i wanted. Problem might be about my wrapper and menu in master page, hiderpanel in page content. I don't know. It doesn't work in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You want your side panel to be at top of all other contents? If yes, Put position fixed to both side panel and top header, and give z-index to sidepanel higher than the header panel

Comment: Yes i want to do it, my top and left content has position:fixed; my page content has absolute. My hider panel has fixed. And my hider panel has higher z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the objects also have a `position: relative;` CSS definition, without it the `z-index` attribute can not work. Alternate values for `position` might be fixed and absolute.

Comment: Yes i want to do it, my top and left content has position:fixed; my page content has absolute. My hider panel has fixed. And my hider panel has higher z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some code. But I suppose it is one of the following reasons:

> **Note:** z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

**The second possible reason:** If a element with `z-index: 100;` has a parent or grand-parent with i.e. `z-index: 1;`, it can't break trough. I mean that another element with `z-index: 2;` (outside of this parent) lays over the element with `z-index: 100;`

Comment: I think thats the second one. My page content has lower z-index than the other contents. So my panel in page content, it cant be on the other contents maybe. I'm curious if i can figure it out with some macigal word :( I don't want to change my master page after all.